# read type-in string with unknown length

Tags: c++, string

in c++, how can we read a string with unknow length (maybe include blank,and very long) which are typed in by user?
getline seems require to know the maximum length.
How to do it?

Comment: You're confusing input length with the size of the buffer that *you* provide to store it in

Answer (score 6):

`cin.getline` needs to know the size of the buffer because it stores into a `char *`. However, you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), which stores into a `string` and can read an arbitrary amount of text.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "Enter something: " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::cout << "You typed " << line << std::endl;
}
```